# Speakers volume lower than it should be

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio, alsa

I have powered speakers connected by USB to Fedora KDE 32 machine.

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0043 C-Media Electronics, Inc. TUK by Kanto

Until recently everything was fine, until I noticed that say at 50% volume it plays quieter than before. It actually plays quieter at every volume level, but at 18% it goes mute completely even though at 19% it's nowhere near the minimum.

Also if I use volume control on speakers or using the remote control, I can't go lower than 15% - it seems that speakers think that 15% is the 0%.

Another thing - when I power off/power up speakers they start playing significantly louder, and after couple seconds they lose decibels. I would guess that when powered up they start playing at the level I've used to them playing, but something kicks in and they go quieter.